# Highcharts - hide y-axis when lines are hidden by user

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts hides the y-axis numbers when you hide all of the lines for that y-axis, but the label still shows up. When you have a lot of labels, this looks ridiculous and confusing.

Is there any way I can make it hide the y-axis label also? Either an option for it in Highcharts or an event that I can hook into for the user clicking the label and manage it myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the axis.setTitle() event provided by highcharts.

here is the api [link](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setTitle%28%29) to it